# Open new window uppon NSAlert

Tags: cocoa, nsalert

I'm using a NSAlert to ask the user to enable Accessibility for assistive devices. Is it possible to have a button that does not close the NSAlert that I could use to just open the UniversalAccess prefpane ?

If not, I suppose I've to create myself that window.

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally alerts close when any button is pressed.  In Mac OS X 10.5 or later you can use `setAccessoryView:` to insert a custom view into the alert, which presumably can contain a button that does anything you want.

Note however that you can't specify where the accessory view goes.  It might have a button in it but the button would show up in the middle of the window instead of along the bottom with the other buttons.  (If you chose a different button style such as a square bevel for your custom button, it might look less out of place.)  To have complete control over layout, you need to make your own alert window.